Issue with Currency Display in Odoo QWeb Report (Odoo 17)
I'm working on a QWeb report in Odoo 17, and I've encountered an issue with the currency symbol display.
When I use the following template in my QWeb report:
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="report_voucher">
            <t t-call="web.html_container">
                <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
                    <!-- Report content here -->
                    <t t-esc="line.debit" t-options="{'widget': 'monetary', 'display_currency': o.currency_id}"/>
                </t>
            </t>
        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>

The currency symbol is displayed incorrectly, e.g., 500.00Â â‚± instead of 500.00 ₱.

However, when I use this template:
<t t-call="web.basic_layout">

The currency symbol is displayed correctly.
Could anyone explain why this is happening and how I can fix the currency symbol display when using web.html_container?
Thanks in advance!

Weird, the Basic Layout is calling the other template. Probably other fonts are used?

yah, same thought, its weird.
I double check my code and I'm not using any fonts.
